# UIToolbar on top of keyboard: Change frame?

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar

I have a `UIToolbar` set to the `inputAccessoryView` of a `UITextView`. This shows the toolbar on top of the keyboard, when editing. I have, however, encountered a problem when rotating the device: the toolbar should become a little less heigh (32 pixels vs 44). When I just update the height of the toolbar, I get a little white space between the toolbar and the keyboard:

[image]

So I used `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` to also update the origin, and then it works when rotating from portrait to landscape. When rotating back up, however, the toolbar is 12 pixel too low and overlapping the keyboard:

[image]

By then, the origin is (0,0) again and setting a negative value didn't help. Any suggestions of how to make it work so that the toolbar changes its size and never overlaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by calling `[textView resignFirstResponder]` in `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `[textView becomeFirstResponder]` in `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`. The system seems to adjust the frame properly.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    didShowKeyboard = [self.textView isFirstResponder];

    [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    CGRect toolbarFrame = [self.navigationController.toolbar bounds];
    self.keyboardToolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;

    if (didShowKeyboard)
        [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Calculating the Origins and sizes you can use Autosizing to render the Controls during rotation.

See this tutorial http://www.bogotobogo.com/XcodeSDK-Chapter4.html

I think this can give you a hint.

Comment: I tried using Autoresizing on the toolbar and the `inputAccessoryView` but it did not work.. I also tried view swapping, but got strange results. How would you swap one toolbar with another? Just updating `inputAccessoryView` did not help and `[toolbar removeFromSuperview]` neither.